# JTable Oracle Timestamp column not displayed

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jtable, oracle11gr2

I have created a 'Jtable' named Department_Table and now using SQL query i am trying to populate my Database table contents to my Jtable.

I have done it successfully but the timestamp column from my Database table is not been correctly displayed.
Can you please help me to find whats wrong with this program.

Code:

```
public void  UpdateTable()
    {        
        try
        {
            Connection conn=Address.getOracleConnection();

            String sql="Select * from department";
            /*
             Using to_char my statement looks like this and it works

            String sql="Select department_id,name,to_char(created_on,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from department";   
            */

            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet res=pst.executeQuery();
            Department_Tabel.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             Notify.showMessageDialog(null,""+e+"","Error Generating Table",Notify.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
departmentid    name                         createdon

1            name1           oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@19eda2c

2            name2              oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@59a34
```

Comment: Try to call `ResultSet.getDate()` or change 'select id,name, to_char(createdon,'MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS') ..`.

Comment: Thank You it is been displayed using to_char .  Can u Please explain how to use ResultSet.getDate().

Comment: You have to call `toTimestamp` on the Oracle data type. Doing a `to_char` is not a very good idea. You lose the entire data type.

Comment: Sorry Michael As a beginner i dont have much idea. Can u please explain me what all changes should i make in the code to ude "toTimestamp" . I have pasted my "to_char" query above

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you understand the mapping and do the formatting in order to display the contents properly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html